# How to personalize dotfiles on gcp instances

Tags: dot-files, google-cloud

On gcp (google cloud), the first time a user connects (via ssh) to a vm a new home directory is created and dotfiles are populated from /etc/skel.  How can I configure things to get user specific dotfiles?